# Need Renovate configuration option to exclude the <version> tag within the <parent> tag of a Maven pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, renovate

Below is my sample renovate configuration file

```
module.exports = {
    endpoint: 'https://git.myOrg.info/',
    password: '${password}',
    username: '${username}',
    platform: 'bitbucket-server',
    repositories: ['myRepo/myService'],
    branchPrefix: 'team/renovate-',
    commitMessagePrefix: 'Renovate : ',

    onboarding: false,
    
    requireConfig: "ignored",
    
    enabledManagers: ["maven", "npm"],

    hostRules: [
       
        {
            hostType: 'maven',
            matchHost: 'https://my.org.io/',
            username: '${user}',
            password: '${key}',
        },
        
        {
            hostType: 'npm',
            matchHost: 'my.org.io,
            username: '${user}',
            password: '${key}',
        }
    ],
    packageRules: [
        {
            matchUpdateTypes: ["major"],
            enabled: false
        },
        
        {
            matchDatasources: ["npm"],
            registryUrls: ["https://my.org.io/..../"]
        },
        {
            matchDatasources: ["maven"],
            registryUrls: ["https://my.org.io/..../"]
        },
        
        {
            matchManagers: ["npm"],
            matchUpdateTypes: ["minor","patch"],
            groupName: "npm minor"
        },
        {
            matchManagers: ["maven"],
            matchUpdateTypes: ["minor","patch"],
            groupName: "maven minor and patch"
        },
    ]
};
```

One of my pom.xml file for a module contains parent tag like below

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.myservice.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>myservice-client-parent</artifactId>
    <version>5.x-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Along with other dependency update, renovate is also updating `<version>5.x-SNAPSHOT</version>` to `<version>5.70.0</version>`.
I don't want renovate to update the parent tag version. How to modify my existing configuration file to avoid this?

I looked at this [document](https://docs.renovatebot.com/configuration-options/#packagerules) but couldn't find any fruitful configuration as per my need. Perhaps I would have missed something here so please point out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this with the configuration as below:

```
ignoreDeps: [
    // ignore parent pom
    "org.myservice.com:myservice-client-parent"
],
```